# In Chrome Extension Running Content Script Can Not Access New Window/Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome Extension that pulls a list of URLs from a main web page,  loops through the URLs, displays them in a new window/tab, and selects buttons on the new page.  I am using jQuery to scrape the list of URLs from the Main Page and buttons on subsequant pages.  I then loop through the URLs one at a time looking for a button element so I can click on it.  The pages load fine but the running content script does not have access to the new active window/tab. Only the main tab is accessible.  So the running content script can not find the button I want to click.  The Extension includes a popup.html, popup.js, content.js, background.js, background.html, and manifest.json.  The manifest includes permissions for tabs, activeTab, and list of web addresses.  The content script area in the manifest has list of URLs it accesses.

When run the the popup.html disappears but the content script runs through urls displaying each in a new tab but the find button comes back as 'undefined'  so the click event fails.  Any ideas on why the content script is not accessing the new tab and possible ways around it.

I have ruled out a timing problem because waited for the page to load and it never finds the button.

i have searched the web the last couple of days.  to no avail.  it could be a a google security problem to do.  I tried different methods of loading page.  I have tried loading page in new window, new tab,  and main tab.  Nothing works.  I have developed code to manually go through each step via a popup button and the code works fine.

//The Content Script Snippets:

//The Listener Snippet:

```
            if (msg.text === 'do_display') {
                editList();
                sendResponse({ count: 1, test_mode: 0 });
            }
```

//Edit List Snippet:

```
            function editList(){
            var links = $("div.item-listing").find("a");
            links.each((l) => console.log("href: " + links[l].href));
            var count = links.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                LinksArray[i] = links[i].href;
            }
            work();
            };
```

//The Work Function Code:

```
            function work() {
                if (LinksArray.length === 0) return;
                var url = LinksArray.shift();
                console.log(url);
                openWindow = window.open(url); //WINDOWS OPEN FINE
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var edit = $("button.edit-listing");
                    console.log("get_edit: " + edit[0]); //FAILS TO FIND BUTTON  "UNDEFINED' 
                    getEdit();
                }, 3000);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    openWindow.close();
                    work();
                }, 30000);
            }
```

running content script should find button but fails.  script does not seem to be focused on new tab.

Comment: I would assume your problem is beacuse you're looking at the DOM when the page hasn't finished loading yet? Instead of using a timeout, try having a look at `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`. You can use it to send a message to your content script when a page has completed loading as a signal to start your `work` function

Comment: It looks like you want to get `button.edit-listing` from a newly opened URL but you're looking for it in the current page. Also, if the URLs are from different domains this entire approach won't work. Instead your background script should open a tab, wait for it to load, run a content script there to get the data, proceed to the next URL. Example: [When opening and scripting multiple tabs, how to make chrome.tabs.executeScript run code in the respective tab?](//stackoverflow.com/a/55346193), you can find more, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I will study the chrome.tabs.onUpdated technique and executeScript example.  I saw those in my searches but they look to complicated to get my head around.  Guess I have to study more.  I also found that making the items a clickable event rather than a load event allowed the content script to see the buttons but timing became a problem.  your techniques should help me resolve the timing issues.

Comment: Okay.  So I have spent the last several days trying to get the suggestions to work but to no avail.  I got the messaging to work between the content script and the background script and the background script opens the new tab fine.  I used the onUpdated method to get the completed status and it works fine.  But the jQuery to find the button it still comes back as undefined.  here is the background code I am using.